# Using SSIS tools?

Tags: ssis

I want to import data from a relational database in order to integrate it and load it in a transit database that I will use to form OLAP cubes. I've seen many tutorials about SSIS and they're all so basic and working on just one data flow task. 
Now I wonder if I have to use one data flow for each table that I gonna bring or for each group of tables which are related to each other. Many details concerning BI tools are still unclear.
I really appreciate your help and if you can propose some advaced tutorials for me that will be grate too. :) 
I've also another question concerning the transit database is it gonna be multidimensional and have I to create an empty one first??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I wonder if I have to use one data flow for each table

Most developers do it this way, mostly for ease of logging, but also having multiple sources and targets in a single data flow task means it multi-threads, and you lose control over it. In my case, in each data flow task I'm grabbing the row counts in the source / inserted / updated / deleted / failed validation / no action, and that's not possible if there are multiple sources and destinations.

> I really appreciate your help and if you can propose some advanced tutorials for me that will be grate too.

I recommend searching [Pragmatic Works free SSIS training webinars](http://pragmaticworks.com/Training/FreeTraining/PastWebinars), and while you're at it see if they are offering an SSIS workshop in your area.  Of course other people will have other preferences, and your mileage may vary. 
   Also, define 'advanced'.

> I've also another question concerning the transit database is it gonna be multidimensional and have I to create an empty one first??

Not enough information here to give you an answer, and how about splitting this off as a separate question with details, as opposed to bundling multiple questions (with an unknown amount of follow-up questions) in a single SO question.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your help and thanks for the link you've proposed too I gonna see it right now. By "advanced" I meant manipulating different sources of data with many tables each one. A tutorial that takes many scenarios into consideration. Because I've already seen many ones and they were similar to each other and not really helpful.

Comment: Now for the last question, I gonna formulate it this way: for each BI solution we are supposed to consider 3 major steps, SSIS --> SSAS --> SSRS: What seems unclear is how to link between the SSIS project and the SSAS one cause normally the "input" of the second one is the "output" of the first? So Am I supposed to use an intermediate database in which I load the data and then use it to construct OLAP cubes in the SSAS project? If yes is it gonna be a new database to define? I hope that I was clearer and Sorry if it's still not !

Comment: Don't think you're going to find many training sessions about 'different' data sources, as most people work with a select few, so to train on all would be a waste of a lot of people's time.  Better to take basic training, then figure it out as you go along.

Comment: Never heard of this before, where'd you get this idea??  --> we are supposed to consider 3 major steps, SSIS --> SSAS --> SSRS